# htaccess redirect if url contains some specific words

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have this rule

```
RewriteRule ^temp1/(.*)$ temp1.php?id=$1
```

but i'm trying to have some conditions like a word
example:

If `.*` has the word `url+temp+var` redirect it to `https://newdomain.example` if not `RewriteRule ^temp1/(.*)$ temp1.php?id=$1`

If it's `https://olddomain.example/temp1/url+temp+var` redirect to `https://newdomain.example`.

Comment: Have you tried anything? You've already done the hard part. (?) A request of the form `https://olddomain/temp1/url+temp+var` is already being passed to your PHP script - why not issue the redirect in PHP?

Comment: So why not just add a RewriteRule before the existing one, that specifically takes care of this one, fixed URL?